# InfoPath & C#: Mouse over / hover events on a calculated value

Tags: c#, infopath

I'm building an InfoPath form with a dashboard section showing 43 tasks as "calculated values". These calculated values are basically just small color coded blocks to quickly tell if the task is complete/pending/late/etc. Each individual task can be assigned to a different user.

What I would like to do is set it up so when the mouse is over the calculated value, it would display additional information in a specific set of fields. I have the basic idea on how to do this, matching the field to the primary key field to pull additional information about the task; my C# knowledge is fairly lackluster though.

My question is: Is this possible in a browser based form? If so could someone point me in the right direction.

If you need any additional information, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can mention static screen tip which shows up on mouseover.
Click Properties -> Click Advanced tab -> Supply text in ‘Screen Tip' field.

But programattically showing something on mouseover could be challenging. I'm yet to come across something like this.

The easiest way will be to create links next to each calculated value and handle the click event in your C# code.

A link basically will be a flattened Button (display set to none) with some underlined text such as 'Click for more info.'

Comment: I was hoping it'd be fairly simple, but this will have to do. Thank you!